# What is wrong with my css command which change parts of menu to new lines when screen is lower than x px?

Tags: css, responsive-design, jinja2, media-queries, display

I would like to change menu when is screen width lower to display menu link each in own line but when I use this, it is still same in one line.
Then menu.jinja is used in another .jinja site where is link to style.css. Is there anything bad in my css command?

style.css

```
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .menu ul li {
        margin-right: 20px;
        padding: 10px; 
        display: block;  //main function
        
    }
}
```

menu.jinja

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                {% if 'role_idone' in session and session['role_idone'] == 1 %}
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('user_manage.user_manage"
                {% endif %}
               <li><a href="property_manage.jinja">Property manage</a></li>
               <li><a href="building_manage.jinja">Building manage</a></li>
         
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet that reproduces your problem? Please use the HTML that's been actually generated by your jinja and not the jinja that generates your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldnt be *display: flex;* in other .menu parts and I changed max-with to min-width and now it works.